# Loading Mesh from X File with Direct X 9 in C++

Tags: c++, directx, mesh

I have been having problems on making a Load Mesh function in C++ for Direct X.  I seem to get this error: "Unhandled exception at 0x00401e64 in _.exe: 0xC00000005: Access violation reading loaction 0x83e05597".  I know it is crashing on this line:

```
D3DXMATERIAL* tempMaterials = (D3DXMATERIAL*)bufMaterial->GetBufferPointer();
```

The whole function looks like this (I have been following along directxtutorial.com so far for direct X help).

```
void LoadModel(Model* model, LPCTSTR File){
LPD3DXBUFFER bufMaterial;

D3DXLoadMeshFromX(File, D3DXMESH_SYSTEMMEM, d3ddev, NULL, &bufMaterial, NULL,
                  &model->numMaterials, &model->Mesh);
OutputDebugString("LOAD MESH \n");

D3DXMATERIAL* tempMaterials = (D3DXMATERIAL*)bufMaterial->GetBufferPointer();
OutputDebugString("GET BUFFER\n");

model->Material = new D3DMATERIAL9[model->numMaterials];
model->Texture = new LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9[model->numMaterials];

OutputDebugString("LOAD MESH \n");

for(DWORD index = 0; index < model->numMaterials; index++)
{
    model->Material[index] = tempMaterials[index].MatD3D;
    model->Material[index].Ambient = model->Material[index].Diffuse;

    // if there is a texture to load, load it
    if(FAILED(D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA(d3ddev,
                                     tempMaterials[index].pTextureFilename,
                                     &model->Texture[index])))
        model->Texture[index] = NULL;    // if there is no texture, set the texture to NULL
}   

return;}
```

I call it like this:

```
LoadModel(networkBase, TEXT("E:\\C++\\Skirmish\\X\\gridbox.x"));
```

But, I have found my old Beginning DirectX book and another web site source that all use this type casting of the material buffer from the temporary material buffer like the line that is crashing is doing.  Please help!

Comment: can i have your login info, i can't effort buy one im 13 years old ;/

Answer (score 1):

The bug is not the cast to `D3DXMATERIAL*`, but probably that `bufMaterial` is not a valid pointer.

`LPD3DXBUFFER` is a typedef for `ID3DXBuffer *` and therefore a pointer to a `ID3DXBuffer` wich has to be initialized before using it. You could do this like so:

```
D3DXCreateBuffer(NumBytes, &bufMaterial);
```

NumBytes should be an integer which specifies the size of the buffer.

Comment: I thought when you pass the reference to the buffer in the D3DXLoadMeshFromX() line it will fill the buffer for you?

Comment: First I thought that too, and I am not quite sure what the doc from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172890(VS.85).aspx means when saying "Pointer to a buffer containing materials data.". Because of your problem I then thought that my suggestion could probably solve it. Have you tried D3DXCreateBuffer? 
Try to print the address that the pointer points to before and after the call to D3DXLoadMeshFromX, maybe that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no materials on your mesh, then it won't return an `ID3DXBuffer` for the materials array because there are no materials.

Did you check `model->numMaterials` after the function returns?

Also, you should initialize your `ID3DXBuffer` pointer to zero before calling the function.

Additionally, consider [linking against the debug D3DX](http://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/direct3d-programming-tip-6-link-against-the-debug-d3dx/) if you aren't already to get additional debug information from D3DX.

Answer (score 0):

ok i took your code to quick test i changed some things but not big changes i hope it will help you!

```
void LoadModel(Model* model, LPCTSTR File)
{ 
 LPD3DXBUFFER bufMaterial;
D3DXLoadMeshFromXW(File, D3DXMESH_SYSTEMMEM, d3ddev, NULL, &bufMaterial, NULL, 
                  &model->numMaterials, &model->Mesh); 
OutputDebugString(L"LOAD MESH \n"); 

D3DXMATERIAL* tempMaterials = (D3DXMATERIAL*)bufMaterial->GetBufferPointer(); 
OutputDebugString(L"GET BUFFER\n"); 

model->Material = new D3DMATERIAL9[model->numMaterials]; 
model->Texture = new LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9[model->numMaterials]; 

OutputDebugString(L"LOAD MESH \n"); 

for(DWORD index = 0; index < model->numMaterials; index++) 
{ 
    model->Material[index] = tempMaterials[index].MatD3D; 
    model->Material[index].Ambient = model->Material[index].Diffuse; 

        // if there is a texture to load, load it 
        if(FAILED(D3DXCreateTextureFromFileA(d3ddev, 
                                     tempMaterials[index].pTextureFilename, 
                                     &model->Texture[index]))) 
                model->Texture[index] = NULL;    // if there is no texture, set the texture to NULL 
}    

return;
}
```

**UPDATE**
something important you may wanna look at is this.

```
struct Model
{
    DWORD numMaterials;
    LPD3DXMESH Mesh;
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9* Texture;
    D3DMATERIAL9* Material;
};
```

this is just simple example i made to help me with my testing. if didn't work try using another animation